# Why is FrameworkElement.VisualChildrenCount protected?

Tags: wpf, protected, adornerlayer, frameworkelement

Here's the background for my question:

1. I would like to know if a particular `System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer` is empty or not.
2. "OK, I'll make the check `myAdornerLayer.VisualChildrenCount > 0`."
3. "Oh well, the property `AdornerLayer.VisualChildrenCount` is protected." (It overrides `System.Windows.FrameworkElement.VisualChildrenCount` which is also protected.)
4. "Hm... That won't stop me. I'll just access `myAdornerLayer.VisualChildrenCount` via reflection."
5. "On the other hand, maybe doing this will have some sort of bad side effect. Maybe `VisualChildrenCount` has been protected for a reason. I'll ask Stack Overflow".

If using reflection is a bad idea, do you have a suggestion for another way of finding out if an `AdornerLayer` is empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `Visual Tree Helper` class, that was made for this purpose..

http://bing.com/search?q=visualTreeHelper